# MySQL: Large table splitting

Tags: mysql, large-data

I have a huge table in a database and I want to split that into several parts physically, maintaining the database scheme.

For example, the table name is TableName and has 2 000 000 rows.

I would like to split that table into four parts, but I want to work in the same way with the table, so

```
select [Column List] from TableName where [Filter]

insert into TableName ([Column List]) values([Values])

update TableName [Updates] where [Filter]

delete from TableName where [filter]
```

would work in the same way after splitting the table as before. Basically I want my database to handle in different threads my queries. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As mentioned by Hammerite partitioning would be much better solution. However, 2 000 000 is not all that much and with good indexes and well designed queries shouldn't work slow at all.

Comment: The problem is that several selects are done by an authomatic project which is running on five threads on each of several servers and the table has a lot of columns too. Sometimes it takes ages to do some simple commands in the database. So we are not talking about running a select query, we are talking about running dozens of queries per second or even more, copying the data to a slave duplicae which is shown on a website. So, in our case, partitioning is the only option. The table is indexed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you should look at [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking into copying data to a separate slave / duplicate; consider implementing that by binary logging, so the replica will read the binary logs to do the replication, rather than doing it manually or programmatically.